# Retrofit: java.net.ProtocolException: Unknown method 'PATCH'

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to PATCH data with Retrofit to my server (rest API spring).

I'm using retrofit 1.9.0.

```
D/Retrofit: ---> HTTP PATCH http://myserver/...
....
D/Retrofit: ---> END HTTP (220-byte body)
D/Retrofit: ---- ERROR http://myserver/...
D/Retrofit: java.net.ProtocolException: Unknown method 'PATCH'; must be one of [OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpURLConnection.java:665)
    at retrofit.client.UrlConnectionClient.execute(UrlConnectionClient.java:37)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:326)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.access$100(RestAdapter.java:220)
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler$2.obtainResponse(RestAdapter.java:278)
    at retrofit.CallbackRunnable.run(CallbackRunnable.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
    at retrofit.Platform$Android$2$1.run(Platform.java:142)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
D/Retrofit: ---- END ERROR
```

I don't know how to solve that. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the retrofit documentation it looks like it is supported in 2.0 and up. Otherwise update your gradle dependencies to use:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.0.0'
}
```

The issue is the built-in HttpUrlConnection. You need to use
OkHttp or Apache HttpClient instead.

My recommendation would be to update to the newer version of retrofit and avoid the hassle.